# Issue downloading Compose for Docker on NixOS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nix, nixos

I am attending a hackathon. It's early morning, and I'm going to sleep before the sun rise.

I am hoping someone here knows how to install Compose for Docker, as it is required for running Gitcoin Web docker.
I am new to Docker and NixOS.

Here is a screenshot of the broken curl command.
[image: failing curl for docker-compose]

I have downloaded it to /usr/bin/ and chmod it, but it wont run. The only other file there is an executable named env.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On NixOS, the Docker Compose package is named `docker_compose`. Simply install `docker_compose` via either `nix-env` or put it in your `configuration.nix` like any other package.

Comment: Thank you sir! I will try it as soon as I am back to HackCU!

Comment: thank you sir, now i have docker-compose in my fresh Nixos!